# Phonegap Push notification to ios using GCM

Tags: android, ios, extjs, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-build

I need inputs on which plugin to use to make the ios push notification working with GCM. I am using phonegap, sencha touch 2.

I have configured GCM, provided the p12 , pem for development. My ios certificate is correct as I am able to send notification to ios through certificate generated using APNS with same p12(pem) file. Phonegap push notification library which I am using is not supporting the ios GCM notification(it supports native ios and gcm android).
I am using :

I found that there is another plugin which does offer new ios GCM integration. Here is the one I found:
https://github.com/gonzaloaune/GCMPushPlugin#readme

When I try to include the plugin in config.xml then build fails.

build fails with message as

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/God.build/Release-iphoneos/God.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GCMPushPlugin.o God/Plugins/cordova-plugin-gcmpushplugin/GCMPushPlugin.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

I am not sure if it is failing as if plugin does not exist ? Anyway my question is which phonegap push notification plugin to use which support ios and android both through GCM.

Please share some pointers on this.

thanks,
amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1199 is outdated and Adobe Phonegap build does not support it (last support till November 2016).  So now using a different phonegap push notification(phonegap-plugin-push) plugin which is supported.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

This is working with sencha touch and phonegap build. Notifications are working with GCM, APNS on ios and android

Answer (score 0):

I did solved the issue and just providing a answer here for those who are facing similar issue. Problem was the phonegap push plugin which I was using was supporting only GCM and not iOS APN notifications. I did google and I found the correct plugin to use.

https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1199

With this all Google (GCM) and ios (APN) notifications are working without any issue